# "Answers" and "Votes Cast" are too close

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page

For example on [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147333/charlesb), Answers and Votes Cast is too close.

[image]

How about like this?

[image]

Comment: +1 for extreme nit picking. You are my hero. Er, uh... YOU is my hero.

Comment: Nice pick :) appreciable

Comment: What isn't this a feature request or bug report? It happens only when there's no paging for answers.

Comment: @Shadow - now it's a bug.

Comment: @Jon good job!! ;)

Comment: @Shadow, heh, I wasn't sure this is a bug. Yes, the issue is because of there is no paging. Ah, Thanks Jon.

Comment: @YOU common sense tells me that the margin should be the same with or without paging so bug indeed..

Comment: @Shadow, the margin is the same.  You just can't tell because the content doesn't line up horizontally when the paging control is visible.

Comment: @jinguy whoops, good catch. Well, so the margin should be bigger when there's no pager. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should now be fixed. It bugged me too.